# Range of values of $k$ for which $\frac{x-2}{x^2-5x+k}$ is unrestricted

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given that $$ f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x^2-5x+k}$$ and that $x$ is real, find: the range of values of $k$ such that the range of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

I attempted this question, by aiming to produce a sketch. Sketching the graph in it's current form doesn't seem very feasible. Therefore, I flipped the function. Examining $\frac{1}{f(x)}$. The reason for that is producing a sketch of a function is usually simple if you can sketch the reciprocal.

$$ \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{x^2-5x+k}{x-2} = (x-3)+\frac{k-6}{x-2} $$

From here, I noted that when $k = 6$, $\frac{1}{f(x)} = x-3$. Hence $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-3}$. Clearly in this case $f(x)$ is unrestricted.

However, I had trouble examining the cases of when $k > 6$ and when $k < 6$. I don't know how to produce sketches for those cases or an alternative way to go about solving for those cases. Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Think of the negative discriminant.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of $f(x)$ is unrestricted"? That the image/range of $f$ is $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thanks for the reply. I've seen some solutions to these types of problems that examine the discriminant. But I don't understand what the discriminant would suggest in such cases. My understanding of the discriminant is that it may be used to determine the number of solutions a quadratic equation will have. $b^2-4ac\geq0$ 2 solutions and $b^2-4ac<0$ means two complex solutions.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Yes, that's correct

Comment: Then your conclusion is incorrect for $k = 6$ because $0$ is not in the range of $f$.

Comment: When $k=6$, you can’t get 0.

Comment: The solution in my textbook includes $k=6$ as a solution. Perhaps there is another meaning for the term 'unrestricted'?

Comment: Could "unrestricted" mean "unbounded"?

Comment: "The solution in my textbook includes $k=6$ as a solution" Then, the question your textbook asks is different from "Find the range of values of $k$ such that the range of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$".  Can you write the given solution in your textbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's handle a special case, when $k=6$, the denominator vanishes at $x=2$, $f$ can't take value $0$. We clearly have the condition that  $k \ne 6$.

For $r$ to be attainable, we need $x$ such that

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2-5x+k} = r$$

$$x-2=rx^2-5rx+kr$$

$$rx^2-(5r+1)x+kr+2=0$$

Hence using discriminant, we would want $$(5r+1)^2-4r(kr+2) \ge 0$$

That is we would want to pick $k$ such that the inequality holds for all $r$.

$$(25-4k)r^2+2r+1 \ge 0$$

For this to hold for all $r$, we need $25-4k > 0$ (for convexity) and $4-4(25-4k) \le 0$ (discriminant).

That is $k < \frac{25}4$ and $1 \le 25-4k$. Along with $k \ne 6$, we conclude that $k < 6$.

Comment: Hello. I follow your solution until fourth line, namely $(5r+1)^2-4r(kr+2) \ge 0$. My understanding of the discriminant is that it may be used to figure out for what range of values we can get our desired solutions. So in this case, solving the inequality would tell us when we have 2 real solutions to our quadratic equation in the third line. How does solving this inequality let us infer the values for which our function maps to the reals?

Comment: That is a quadratic inequality. If the leading terms is positive, then it is convex and not linear, and if the discriminant is non-positive, then the quadratic function is nonnegative.

Comment: I understand your reasoning for solving the quadratic inequality and arriving at $ k < 6$. But why did you use the discriminant in this case? That is $b^2-4ac \ge 0$ and how did it give us the correct range of values for which our function $f(x)$ maps to reals?

Comment: I use discriminat twice actually, for the first time where the variable is $x$, I obtain $(25-4k)r^2+2r+1 \ge 0$. For this to hold, I look at the quadratic inequality with $r$ being the variable, we want the discriminant to be non-positive, in that case, the convex quadratic in $r$ doesn't cut the horizontal axis twice, ensuring nonnegativity.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to analyse the behaviour of the graph of a rational function near roots and vertical asymptotes, you can use this to your advantage. First, note that $2$ is a single root of the function whenever $x - 2$ is not a factor of the denominator (i.e. whenever $k \neq 6$). Further, whenever the denominator has two distinct real roots, there are two vertical asymptotes. If $(2, 0)$ is between them, since $2$ is a single root, the function is positive on one side of $x = 2$ and negative on the other, and since there are vertical asymptotes on each side, you get a range of $\mathbb R$. There are still more cases left, but see if that can't get you started.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you--the range can't be $\mathbb{R}$ due to the asymptotes, right? It's $\mathbb{R}$ minus $x = r, s$ where $r,s$ are the two roots of the denominator. Have I learned this/remembered this wrong?

Comment: The range is the set of *outputs*.

Comment: /facepalm. Yes, of course it is. I know that. My brain was not braining when I commented, apparently.